# How to find $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \max \{f_1(x),f_2(x),\cdots,f_n(x)\}$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

How to do this optimization ?
$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}_+^K} \max \{f_1(x),f_2(x),\cdots,f_{N-1}(x)\}$$

where : 
$$
f_l(x)  = |\sum_{i \in P} x_i w^{il} |, \qquad w= e^{-j\frac{2\pi}N}
$$
$$
P \subset \{1,2,\cdots,N-1\} , \quad |P|=K
$$

I know that 
$$
\max \{f_1(x),f_2(x),\cdots,f_{N-1}(x)\} \geq \frac1{N-1} \left(f_1(x)+f_2(x)+\cdots+f_{N-1}(x)\right)
$$
And equality is hold iff $f_1(x) = f_2(x) = \cdots = f_{N-1}(x)$

But is this the tightest lower bound or there would be a better lower bound ?

Comment: What are $(f_i)$ ?

Comment: $f_i(x)$ are real functions

Comment: It might not exist... Take $f_i = Id_\Bbb R$

Comment: @xavierm02 I didn't got what you mean. Would you mind explaining a little more?

Comment: $\min\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \max \{Id_\Bbb R(x),Id_\Bbb R(x),\cdots,Id_\Bbb R(x)\}=\min\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \max \{x,x,\cdots,x\}=\min\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} x$ does not exist.

Comment: @xavierm02 Excuse me. What is $I d_{\mathbb{R}}(x)$?

Comment: You can't take the $\min$ on an infinite set, you need to use $\inf$ and to make sure that the set the values are in is bounded and complete. $Id_\Bbb R:\begin{array}{l}\Bbb R \to \Bbb R\\x\mapsto x\end{array}$. It's a function that simply returns its input.

Comment: No. Take $f(x)=xe^{-x}$. Then $\min\limits_{x\in \Bbb R}=0$. Same goes for $g(x)=f(x-1)$ but $\max\{f(x),g(x)\}$ will never be $0$ but when $x\to +\infty$, $f(x)\to 0$. So the $\inf$ exists but not the $\min$. See `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+exp%28-x%29*%7Cx%7C+and+exp%28-%28x-1%29%29*%7Cx-1%7C`

Comment: If those are the functions you want to solve this for, add them to your post.